# Associating new model with user id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm (very) new to ror and have read many tutorials for this issue but none seem to work.  I'm trying to let one user create one booth to sell things.

This is my db migration:

```
class CreateBooths < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :booths do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :booths, [:user_id]
  end
end
```

Here is the booth controller:

```
class BoothsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user

def new
    @booth = Booth.new
  end

 def create
    @booth = current_user.booths.build(booth_params)
    if @booth.save
      flash[:success] = "Congrats on opening your booth!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end



  private

    def booth_params
      params.require(:booth).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

And this is the booth model:

```
class Booth < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

I also added this to the user model:

```
has_one :booth, dependent: :destroy
```

When I include `validates :user_id, presence: true` it won't save to the db.  When I exclude it, it saves but does not include a user id in the database.  If you are still reading thank you and I hope you can help!

Comment: Does `current_user` have an `id`?

Comment: @ptd : If `current_user` wasn't available then OP would have been asking: Why there's undefined method `booths` for nil class. :)

Comment: @ptd yes, current user had id.  The answer below worked well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `create` method of your `BoothsController` to this:

```
def create
  @booth = current_user.build_booth(booth_params)
  if @booth.save
    flash[:success] = "Congrats on opening your booth!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Here, you have one-to-one association between user and booth, and that's why you have to instantiate `booth` for `current_user` using `build_<singular_association_name>`, which is `build_booth` and pass params to it: `build_booth(booth_params)`.

`booths.build(booth_params)` works for one-to-many association, for example: user has many booths, not vice a versa.

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked like a charm and I appreciate the explanation.